# Delete Derby row after one year

Tags: sql, delete-row

I want to check the oldest record in Derby database to see if its older than one year .... then delete this record. My code I have is not working for me.

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
                LocalDate oneYearOld = now.minusDays(365);
                System.out.println( "now: " + now );
                System.out.println( "OneYearOld: " + oneYearOld);
                System.out.println( "SQL Date: " + sqlDate);          

                PreparedStatement stmtB = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM TEST5 WHERE 'DateDate' > 'oneYearOld'"); 
                stmtB.executeUpdate(); // Deletes any call record over one year old
```

Comment: Best practice is to use a parameter for your oneYearOld value and pass that to the query. Use this site as a guide http://bobby-tables.com/java

Comment: ok!  .... but is that why my prepared Statement is not working??

Comment: Well you are passing a string to your sql query called 'oneYearOld'. That isn't a date, it's a string. You need to pass the date variable.